# Auf der Webseite "ihrer" oder "Ihrer" Firma?

Tags: adjective, capitalization

Ich will eine Bewerbung an eine Firma schicken.
Ich bin mir nicht sicher ob der erste Satz richtig ist.
Der Satz lautet:

> Auf der Webseite ihrer Firma habe ich erfahren, dass Sie auf das
>   nächste Jahr eine Stelle anbieten.

Muss man in diesem Fall "ihrer" gross oder klein schreiben?

Comment: auf das nächste Jahr -> im nächsten Jahr bzw. nächstes Jahr bzw. für das nächste Jahr

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ja, es muss groß geschrieben werden, denn wie auch das "Sie" im Nebensatz ist dies eine persönliche Anrede, die groß geschrieben werden muss. siehe [hier](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D84)

Comment: Nur die höfliche, persönliche Anrede *muss* groß geschrieben werden: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Gross-oder-Kleinschreibung-von-duDu-und-ihrIhr

Comment: @jarnbjo Falsch, hier geht es um die höfliche Anrede "Sie", welche **immer** groß geschrieben werden muss (https://www.kapiert.de/deutsch/klasse-9-10/sprache-untersuchen/wortarten/anredepronomen-richtig-schreiben-und-verwenden/)

Comment: @Sentry Ich schreibe doch, dass die höfliche Anrede groß geschrieben werden muss. Die Antwort klingt so, als ob persönliche Anreden allgemein groß geschrieben werden müssen.

Comment: Nun, bis zur 96er Reform wurde meines Wissens auch Du als Anrede in Briefen groß geschrieben.

Comment: @jarnbjo Ach so, ich habe deinen Kommentar aufgrund des Links so verstanden, dass du "du/Du" und "ihr/Ihr" verstanden hast und nicht "Sie"